# Which is better? Trigger or Select sql then update records? for related tables multiple row updating

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, triggers

Scenario: 
Entity 1 can have 0 or more Entity 2.

What trying to do:
When a field in Entity 1 is updated, a field in Entity 2 is consecutively updated.

What I'm doing:
Update field in Entity 1 by update sql, then querying related Entity 2 records (using `SELECT ATTR FROM ENTITY2 WHERE ENTITY1.ID = ENTITY2.ENT1_ID`) just to get the old value of ENTITY2 attr before doing an update on that records. Type of update (e.g. Subtract or add) on ENTITY2 record is based on the update value on ENTITY1.

Alternative :
Using triggers to consecutively update these related records.

(I still plan to study to implement triggers but I am not sure if it is worth it.
Any help from this also please? Or links?)

Is it better to use triggers? Or just stick to my current solution (which I think is quite slow due to the number of sql executions but easier to track down).

Comment: it depends on whats your priority, *update entity2 asap* or *tracking info*. if looking for event based transactions, go for triggers

Comment: Personally I prefer doing it in the database with a trigger.  That way any future code I write, or any manual updates I have to do, get the data integrity enforced with them as well automatically.  If I do it in the code, I might forget to update entity2 sometime when I update entity1 and that would not be good.

Answer (score 0):

There are people, such as [Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html) who believe triggers should be used as little as possible, if at all.
There are others, such as [Toon Koppelaars](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.co.uk/) who believe they should be used, if their use is considered carefully.

I am of the second camp and believe triggers may be used. However, this use should not be to 'automagically' cause cascade actions such as you are suggesting. Instead these triggers may be used to enforce integrity constraints that cannot be declared using the standard mechanism of a table constraint clause i.e. the triggers themselves do no DML other than SELECT from tables.
(note: there are other mechanisms by which these constraints may be enforced, including materialized views or the introduction of additional columns and the use of specific indexing strategies) Therefore, I would suggest another alternative. Create triggers - or use these alternative mechanisms - to ensure no data that breaks your integrity constraints can be committed. Then create APIs, using PL/SQL, that encapsulate the multi-table data amendments that are required to ensure the integrity constraints are not broken and use these as your update path.

In this way you can be assured that no invalid data exists in the database, but also that the actual DML required to achieve this is not hidden across the database in multiple program units and triggers but is stated explicitly in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Kyte is brilliant. But he is, at heart, still just a DBA. Always keep that in mind when considering his advice on table design.

Can triggers be overused? Of course. But here's the rub: *anything* can be overused. I lean toward triggers because there is just no way to guarantee that all data manipulation will go through your app or any single channel. Or, if possible, define a foreign key relationship and let "cascade update" take care of everything. Tricky, I admit, and could be problematic, but don't reject any solution out of hand.

Having said that, I don't know if a trigger for this purpose is called for. I don't know why you are duplicating the data to a field in a different table. Without knowing your overall design and what you are trying to accomplish, there is no way to judge. But consider keeping data in one field in one table then use a view to expose that field as part of a second "table." Change the data where it resides, viola, it is now changed wherever it appears.

Performance hit? Yes. But keeping duplicate data in different places and keeping them synchronized is a data integrity hit. Only you know (or are in a position to find out) which way this balance tilts.

Oh, can views be overused? Of course. But there's always that rub I mentioned; and besides, views are so chronically *underused* in most databases that overuse would be a long way away.